# Integrating Angular 4 with GoJs

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Can somebody help me to convert this code to Angular 4? I have tried for minimal it's working fine but when it comes to flowchart something is missing and I am unable to find that.

Here is my Component.ts file I have attached.

Functions such as Save() and Load() are not working. Because of document.getelementbyid.

How to change this to angular 4 service.

HTML Code:

```
  <div id="sample">
        <div style="width: 100%; white-space: nowrap;">
            <span style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; width: 100px">
                <div id="myPaletteDiv" style="border: solid 1px black; height: 720px"></div>
            </span> <span style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; width: 80%">
                <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
                <div align="center" #myDiagramDiv
                    style="border: solid blue 1px; width: 1000px; height: 1000px"></div>
            </span>
        </div>
        <p>

        </p>
        <button id="SaveButton" (click)="save()">Save</button>
        <button (click)="load()">Load</button>
        Diagram Model saved in JSON format:
        <p>

        </p>
        <textarea id="mySavedModel" style="width: 100%; height: 300px">{ "class": "go.GraphLinksModel",
     "linkFromPortIdProperty": "fromPort",
     "linkToPortIdProperty": "toPort",
     "nodeDataArray": [ 
    {"key":-1, "category":"Start", "loc":"175 0", "text":"Start"},
    {"key":1, "loc":"175 100", "text":"Entity: Amount"},
    {"key":6, "loc":"175.13616240146848 297.0937263794408", "text":"Entity: Account Number"},
    {"key":-2, "category":"End", "loc":"159.17859842349642 758.71806500378", "text":"End"},
    {"text":"Amount == 100", "figure":"Diamond", "key":-3, "loc":"174.8125 189.4553503941259"},
    {"text":"Account Number == 123456", "figure":"Diamond", "key":-6, "loc":"173.084824802937 389.8656732534283"},
    {"key":-7, "loc":"173.40848720440562 527.7383651873449", "text":"Entity: Pin Number"},
    {"text":"Pin Number <= 1234", "figure":"Diamond", "key":-8, "loc":"173.94866240146834 653.3361408055284"}
    ],
     "linkDataArray": [ 
    {"from":-1, "to":1, "fromPort":"B", "toPort":"T", "points":[175,24.773340092148892,175,34.77334009214889,175,54.16780789397485,175.0000000000001,54.16780789397485,175.0000000000001,73.5622756958008,175.0000000000001,83.5622756958008]},
    {"from":1, "to":-3, "fromPort":"B", "toPort":"T", "points":[175.0000000000001,116.43772430419924,175.0000000000001,126.43772430419924,175.0000000000001,136.75881304496335,174.8125,136.75881304496335,174.8125,147.07990178572746,174.8125,157.07990178572746]},
    {"from":-3, "to":6, "fromPort":"B", "toPort":"T", "visible":true, "points":[174.8125,221.83079900252432,174.8125,231.83079900252432,174.8125,247.27453838678335,175.13616240146848,247.27453838678335,175.13616240146848,262.7182777710424,175.13616240146848,272.7182777710424]},
    {"from":6, "to":-6, "fromPort":"B", "toPort":"T", "points":[175.13616240146848,321.46917498783927,175.13616240146848,331.46917498783927,175.13616240146848,331.54197551223535,173.084824802937,331.54197551223535,173.084824802937,331.61477603663144,173.084824802937,341.61477603663144]},
    {"from":-6, "to":-7, "fromPort":"B", "toPort":"T", "visible":true, "points":[173.084824802937,438.11657047022516,173.084824802937,448.11657047022516,173.084824802937,474.70860567668547,173.40848720440562,474.70860567668547,173.40848720440562,501.3006408831457,173.40848720440562,511.3006408831457]},
    {"from":-6, "to":1, "fromPort":"R", "toPort":"R", "visible":true, "points":[328.8833477521557,389.8656732534283,338.8833477521557,389.8656732534283,338.8833477521557,100.00000000000003,292.4533048880408,100.00000000000003,246.0232620239259,100.00000000000003,236.0232620239259,100.00000000000003], "text":"No"},
    {"from":-3, "to":-7, "fromPort":"L", "toPort":"L", "visible":true, "points":[53.215850830078125,189.4553503941259,43.215850830078125,189.4553503941259,44,189.4553503941259,44,189.4553503941259,4,189.4553503941259,4,452,36,452,36,527.7383651873449,88.93497646221812,527.7383651873449,98.93497646221812,527.7383651873449], "text":"No"},
    {"from":-7, "to":-8, "fromPort":"B", "toPort":"T", "points":[173.40848720440562,544.1760894915442,173.40848720440562,554.1760894915442,173.40848720440562,582.568390844337,173.94866240146834,582.568390844337,173.94866240146834,610.96069219713,173.94866240146834,620.96069219713]},
    {"from":-8, "to":-7, "fromPort":"R", "toPort":"R", "visible":true, "points":[330.5989919913121,653.3361408055284,340.5989919913121,653.3361408055284,340.5989919913121,527.7383651873449,299.2404949689526,527.7383651873449,257.8819979465931,527.7383651873449,247.88199794659312,527.7383651873449], "text":"No"},
    {"from":-8, "to":-2, "fromPort":"B", "toPort":"T", "visible":true, "points":[173.94866240146834,685.7115894139268,173.94866240146834,695.7115894139268,173.94866240146834,711.9038126785827,159.1785984234963,711.9038126785827,159.1785984234963,728.0960359432383,159.1785984234963,738.0960359432383]}
    ]}
      </textarea>

    </div>
```

Typescript Code :

```
import {Component, ElementRef, AfterViewInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import * as go from "gojs";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-flowchart',
  templateUrl: './flowchart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./flowchart.component.css']
})
export class FlowchartComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  name = 'GoJS';

  @ViewChild('myDiagramDiv')
  element: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {

    const $ = go.GraphObject.make;

    const myDiagram: go.Diagram = $(go.Diagram, this.element.nativeElement,
      {
        initialContentAlignment: go.Spot.Center,  // center the content
        "undoManager.isEnabled": true  // enable undo & redo
      });


    const myPalette: go.Palette =
      $(go.Palette, "myPaletteDiv",  // must name or refer to the DIV HTML element
        {
          "animationManager.duration": 800, // slightly longer than default (600ms) animation
          nodeTemplateMap: myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap,  // share the templates used by myDiagram
          model: new go.GraphLinksModel([  // specify the contents of the Palette
            {category: "Start", text: "Start"},
            {text: "Step"},
            {text: "???", figure: "Diamond"},
            {category: "End", text: "End"},
            {category: "Comment", text: "Comment"}
          ])
        });


    myDiagram.nodeTemplate =
      $(go.Node, "Auto",
        $(go.Shape, "RoundedRectangle", {strokeWidth: 0},
          new go.Binding("fill", "color")),
        $(go.TextBlock,
          {margin: 8},
          new go.Binding("text", "key"))
      );


    myDiagram.addDiagramListener("Modified", function(e) {
      const button = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("SaveButton");
      if (button) {
        button.disabled = !myDiagram.isModified;
      }
      const idx = document.title.indexOf("*");
      if (myDiagram.isModified) {
        if (idx < 0) {
          document.title += "*";
        }
      } else {
        if (idx >= 0) {
          document.title = document.title.substr(0, idx);
        }
      }
    });


    function nodeStyle() {
      return [
        // The Node.location comes from the "loc" property of the node data,
        // converted by the Point.parse static method.
        // If the Node.location is changed, it updates the "loc" property of the node data,
        // converting back using the Point.stringify static method.
        new go.Binding("location", "loc", go.Point.parse).makeTwoWay(go.Point.stringify),
        {
          // the Node.location is at the center of each node
          locationSpot: go.Spot.Center,
          // isShadowed: true,
          // shadowColor: "#888",
          //  handle mouse enter/leave events to show/hide the ports
          mouseEnter: function(e, obj) {showPorts(obj.part, true);},
          mouseLeave: function(e, obj) {showPorts(obj.part, false);}
        }
      ];
    }

    function makePort(name, spot, output, input) {
      // the port is basically just a small circle that has a white stroke when it is made visible
      return $(go.Shape, "Circle",
        {
          fill: "transparent",
          stroke: null,  // this is changed to "white" in the showPorts function
          desiredSize: new go.Size(8, 8),
          alignment: spot, alignmentFocus: spot,  // align the port on the main Shape
          portId: name,  // declare this object to be a "port"
          fromSpot: spot, toSpot: spot,  // declare where links may connect at this port
          fromLinkable: output, toLinkable: input,  // declare whether the user may draw links to/from here
          cursor: "pointer"  // show a different cursor to indicate potential link point
        });
    }


    const lightText = 'whitesmoke';
    myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap.add("",  // the default category
      $(go.Node, "Spot", nodeStyle(),
        // the main object is a Panel that surrounds a TextBlock with a rectangular Shape
        $(go.Panel, "Auto",
          $(go.Shape, "Rectangle",
            {fill: "#00A9C9", stroke: null},
            new go.Binding("figure", "figure")),
          $(go.TextBlock,
            {
              font: "bold 11pt Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif",
              stroke: lightText,
              margin: 8,
              maxSize: new go.Size(160, NaN),
              wrap: go.TextBlock.WrapFit,
              editable: true
            },
            new go.Binding("text").makeTwoWay())
        ),
        // four named ports, one on each side:
        makePort("T", go.Spot.Top, false, true),
        makePort("L", go.Spot.Left, true, true),
        makePort("R", go.Spot.Right, true, true),
        makePort("B", go.Spot.Bottom, true, false)
      ));

    myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap.add("Start",
      $(go.Node, "Spot", nodeStyle(),
        $(go.Panel, "Auto",
          $(go.Shape, "Circle",
            {minSize: new go.Size(40, 40), fill: "#79C900", stroke: null}),
          $(go.TextBlock, "Start",
            {font: "bold 11pt Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif", stroke: lightText},
            new go.Binding("text"))
        ),
        // three named ports, one on each side except the top, all output only:
        makePort("L", go.Spot.Left, true, false),
        makePort("R", go.Spot.Right, true, false),
        makePort("B", go.Spot.Bottom, true, false)
      ));

    myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap.add("End",
      $(go.Node, "Spot", nodeStyle(),
        $(go.Panel, "Auto",
          $(go.Shape, "Circle",
            {minSize: new go.Size(40, 40), fill: "#DC3C00", stroke: null}),
          $(go.TextBlock, "End",
            {font: "bold 11pt Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif", stroke: lightText},
            new go.Binding("text"))
        ),
        // three named ports, one on each side except the bottom, all input only:
        makePort("T", go.Spot.Top, false, true),
        makePort("L", go.Spot.Left, false, true),
        makePort("R", go.Spot.Right, false, true)
      ));

    myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap.add("Comment",
      $(go.Node, "Auto", nodeStyle(),
        $(go.Shape, "File",
          {fill: "#EFFAB4", stroke: null}),
        $(go.TextBlock,
          {
            margin: 5,
            maxSize: new go.Size(200, NaN),
            wrap: go.TextBlock.WrapFit,
            textAlign: "center",
            editable: true,
            font: "bold 12pt Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif",
            stroke: '#454545'
          },
          new go.Binding("text").makeTwoWay())
        // no ports, because no links are allowed to connect with a comment
      ));


    myDiagram.linkTemplate =
      $(go.Link,  // the whole link panel
        {
          routing: go.Link.AvoidsNodes,
          curve: go.Link.JumpOver,
          corner: 5, toShortLength: 4,
          relinkableFrom: true,
          relinkableTo: true,
          reshapable: true,
          resegmentable: true,
          // mouse-overs subtly highlight links:
          mouseEnter: function(e, link) {link.findObject("HIGHLIGHT").stroke = "rgba(30,144,255,0.2)";},
          mouseLeave: function(e, link) {link.findObject("HIGHLIGHT").stroke = "transparent";}
        },
        new go.Binding("points").makeTwoWay(),
        $(go.Shape,  // the highlight shape, normally transparent
          {isPanelMain: true, strokeWidth: 8, stroke: "transparent", name: "HIGHLIGHT"}),
        $(go.Shape,  // the link path shape
          {isPanelMain: true, stroke: "gray", strokeWidth: 2}),
        $(go.Shape,  // the arrowhead
          {toArrow: "standard", stroke: null, fill: "gray"}),
        $(go.Panel, "Auto",  // the link label, normally not visible
          {visible: false, name: "LABEL", segmentIndex: 2, segmentFraction: 0.5},
          new go.Binding("visible", "visible").makeTwoWay(),
          $(go.Shape, "RoundedRectangle",  // the label shape
            {fill: "#F8F8F8", stroke: null}),
          $(go.TextBlock, "Yes",  // the label
            {
              textAlign: "center",
              font: "10pt helvetica, arial, sans-serif",
              stroke: "#333333",
              editable: true
            },
            new go.Binding("text").makeTwoWay())
        )
      );

    function showPorts(node, show) {
      const diagram = node.diagram;
      if (!diagram || diagram.isReadOnly || !diagram.allowLink) {
        return;
      }
      node.ports.each(function(port) {
        port.stroke = (show ? "white" : null);
      });
    }

    function save() {
      (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("mySavedModel")).value = myDiagram.model.toJson();
      myDiagram.isModified = false;
    }
    function load() {
      myDiagram.model = go.Model.fromJson((<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("mySavedModel")).value);
    }

    function showLinkLabel(e) {
      const label = e.subject.findObject("LABEL");
      if (label !== null) {
        label.visible = (e.subject.fromNode.data.figure === "Diamond");
      }
    }
    // temporary links used by LinkingTool and RelinkingTool are also orthogonal:
    myDiagram.toolManager.linkingTool.temporaryLink.routing = go.Link.Orthogonal;
    myDiagram.toolManager.relinkingTool.temporaryLink.routing = go.Link.Orthogonal;
    load();  // load an initial diagram from some JSON text
    // initialize the Palette that is on the left side of the page

    // The following code overrides GoJS focus to stop the browser from scrolling
    // the page when either the Diagram or Palette are clicked or dragged onto.
    function customFocus() {
      const x = window.scrollX || window.pageXOffset;
      const y = window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset;
      go.Diagram.prototype.doFocus.call(this);
      window.scrollTo(x, y);
    }
    myDiagram.doFocus = customFocus;
    myPalette.doFocus = customFocus;

    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
  }

  // Show the diagram's model in JSON format that the user may edit

 }
```

Comment: Looks more like a job rather than a question. *How to change this to angular 4 service* - it shouldn't be a service. Components and directives interact with DOM. Services don't.

Answer (score 4):

I have got a similar code running in Angular 4.

As per the code shared whatever is inside myDiagram is not available in the scope of Angular Component and cant call save() or Load() from your Angular component or html.

You should use Event triggers of goJs to handle these. It is easy to grab the Div element inside goJs rather than trying to grab the reference of goJs's myDiagram inside Angular.

```
 ngAfterViewInit() {
   var _this = this;

   function init() {
       var $ = go.GraphObject.make;

       //all your myDiagram initialization and functions goes here

       //listen to any changes and save the changes to Angular model
       myDiagram.addModelChangedListener(function (evt: any) {
            _this.saveTemplateData = myDiagram.model.toJson();
            myDiagram.isModified = false;
        });

       //listen for a object drag drop inside goJs canvas and capture it in angular component
      myDiagram.addDiagramListener("ExternalObjectsDropped", (e: any) => {
            _this.newObjectDropped(e.subject);
        });
   }
}
```

There are hundreds of events like the above example. goJs is excellent when come to scalability and rich in  features.

You can refer to the Angular 2 Sample project inside projects/angular-sample in the below link.

https://gojs.net/latest/doc/download.html

This ofcourse is different from the above code and gets goJs into your angular component.

Comment: My attempt to run this failed - You can refer to the Angular 2 Sample project inside projects/angular-sample in the below link.
https://gojs.net/latest/doc/download.html

Comment: The sample project is now out of date and not guaranteed to be in sync with the GitHub repository. You can find the latest version of the Angular Basic sample project at GitHub in repo "**GoJs-Projects**": https://github.com/NorthwoodsSoftware